# SQL Server computed column based on join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables:

Table 1:

```
id name
--------
1 Mark
2 Anna
```

Table 2:

```
id active_name
--------------
2 Anna
```

I want to have a 3rd table or view:

```
id name isActive
--------------------
1 Mark  No
2 Anna Yes
```

How do I do that in SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `left join` and `case` expression:

```
select t1.id, t1.name,
       (case when t2.id is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end) as isActive
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t2.id = t1.id and t2.name = t1.name;
```